# Is there a maximum limit on running concurrent threads (Python)?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I am reading hundreds of tweets where I inspect the URLs. I am using multithreading for this task as the URL reading takes more than a second. However, I am not sure how many threads can I run in parallel at a time in this situation?

```
import Queue
import threading
q = Queue.Queue()
thread limit = 100

for tweet in tweets[0:threadlimit]:
            t = threading.Thread(target=process_tweet, args=(q, tweet))
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()


    for tweet in tweets[0:threadlimit]:
          tweet = q.get()
```

The reason I am asking this that when I use a thread limit of 100 then it works fine but for a threadlimit of 200, it gets stuck.

Platform: Linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operating system is always having some limits on the number of threads, and each thread uses some resources (notably some space, perhaps a megabyte, for the thread's [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)). So it is not reasonable to have lots of threads. Details are operating system and computer specific. On Linux, see [getrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html) for `RLIMIT_STACK` (the default stack size) and `RLIMIT_NPROC` (number of processes, actually tasks, including threads, you are permitted to have).. and also [pthread_attr_setstacksize(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_attr_setstacksize.3.html) & [pthread_create(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html).

Threads are often heavy on resources (so read about [green threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads)). You don't want to have many (e.g. thousands, or even a hundred) of them on a laptop or desktop (some supercomputers or costly servers have hundreds of cores with [NUMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_memory_access), then you could try having more threads).

Read also about the [C10K problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem).

Common implementations of Python use a *single* [Global Interpreter Lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) so having lots of threads is not effective. I would recommend using a [thread pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool) of a reasonable size (perhaps configurable, and probably a few dozens at most).

Consider using [PycURL](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/index.html) and probably its [MULTI](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/curlmultiobject.html#curlmultiobject) interface (see the documentation of the [relevant C API](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-multi.html) in libcurl). Think in terms of an [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) (and perhaps [continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style)).